# Organization Chart

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise

Does anyone know of a free organisation chart or how one would go about building one? Ideally need to inspect the Profile service and produce a chart with images.

The built in Organisation chart is good but doesn't give the preferred layout of a flowchart.

Comment: Have you tried the built in org chart webpart?

Comment: Prefer flowchart layout which the inbuilt doesnt provide.